# Using Ghostscript to change page size from A4 and other to Letter

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I recently asked [this question about changing paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223691/scaling-pdf-file-using-ghostscript/40224891#40224891) and have a command that scales properly most of time:

`gs  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile= $outFile -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=792 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612 -dPDFFitPage -dFIXEDMEDIA $inFile`

We need to have it generate output pages that are US Letter.  I have two problem files I can post.  One needs extra whitespace; the other just needs a very small rescaling but it gets a wildly different output.

The [first file](http://secure.tracksmit.com/demo/A4Sample.pdf) is an A4 file.  The command scales it to a height of 792 and the width is scaled to 559.667.  It's scaled accurately, but we need whitespace either on both sides or on the right.  How can I modify my command (or run a second command) to do this?

The [second file](http://secure.tracksmit.com/demo/gre-NON-LETTER.pdf) is 8.52" x 11.02".  For this one I get an output file that is 549.127 x 709.8 pts and I don't get it at all.  0.02" is within our printing tolerances so we can let it go, but a) I'd rather have just one process b) maybe the issue isn't the small scaling adjustments and maybe it will be a problem for other files.

Answer (score 1):

These, along with your previous question, are all related to the myriad different Boxes available in a PDF file, and the various ways that a PDF processor will deal with the available Boxes.

For your first file; the output of pdfwrite has a MediaBox of 612x792 but a CropBox of [26.1662903 0 585.83374 792.0] which is (of course) not Letter. Its the result of scaling A4 down to Letter and centring that scaled down area on the Letter media.

If you remove the CropBox (using a binary editor) and open the file in Acrobat you will see that the white space is evenly distributed left and right of the page.

So really its up to your printing process. Either you need to tell that process to use the MediaBox and ignore the CropBox, or have it centre the CropBox on the media when the CropBox is not the same as the media.

Your second file has a MediaBox of 684x864 which is 9.5x12 inches. However it has a TrimBox which is [33.8027 33.7217 647.533 827.028] doing the arithmetic that works out is 8.524x11.018 inches.

Clearly Acrobat (or whatever you are using to get the size) is using the TrimBox, not the MediaBox. Ghostscript uses the MediaBox by default, if you want it to use a different *Box then you haver to tell it so. Try adding `-dUseTrimBox` to your command line. See my answer to your previous question :-)

Comment: Thank you again for another detailed reply, Ken.  Clearly I've got a bit to learn about the inner workings of PDF.  Am I on the right track with trying to automate the process using pdfinfo and gs? We're scripting it in PHP (not that it matters a ton).

Comment: We're trying to do this entirely through automation, so for the first file I tried -dUseMediaBox (I'm not sure how to tell it to ignore CropBox).  I don't control the print process, so my goal can be to center the CropBox on the media in software.  For the second file, -dUseTrimBox brings it to 612.00 x 791.07. Here too, Crop/TrimBox centered on the media would be perfectly fine.  But I am not at all seeing how to do it.  FWIW, I am using gs v8.70.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't (or shouldn't) need to tell Ghostscript to ignore the CropBox, it always uses the MediaBox, there is no switch 'UseMediaBox' for this reason, its the default behaviour. The CropBox *is* centred on the Media, that's why the bottom left corner isn't 0,0. You **really** need to update your version of Ghostscript. 8.70 is now 7 years old and I have no idea how it behaves in this regard (and no inclination to research it!). I can't really offer you an opinion about automating your prcoess because I don't really understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: Sorry if I've been unclear.  I'll update the original post with what I'm trying to accomplish (in short, receiving PDFs from the public and resizing them to 8.5x11) and some more specific data.  Unfortunately 8.70 is what is available through the default yum repos on an AWS instance with Amazon Linux.  I'll get a newer version on over the weekend and retry.  Thanks!

Comment: Well the goal is fair, but the problem (as you're discovering) is resize **what** Box, exactly. PDF files can have 5 different boxes; MediaBox, CropBox, BleedBox, TrimBox and ArtBox. Ghostscript defaults to using the MediaBox but can be told which of the others you want to use. But its up to you to figure out which one is 'correct'! The scaling does indeed produce the correct MediaBox, but it adds a CropBox to limit the area to the scaled original content. If you can't live with that then you'll need to change PDFFitPage. Right at the moment I can't see a solution for that.